# Does anybody using SERAIL type instead of SEQUENCE in POSTGRESQL 13 Recently?

Tags: postgresql

Could you please help me to choose SERAIL vs Sequence in project..
Which is best for future use?
I'm using POSTGRESQL13 for project Can I use SERAIL type

Comment: Do you mean "SERIAL vs IDENTITY"? Serial is implemented using a sequence so...

Comment: Not really older version i have created sequence separately using create sequence command, Can i change those columns into serial type. ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no serial type.  Using `serial` is more like a macro, which creates a column of type `integer`, and a sequence to fill it.  If you describe the table it `\d` or dump the create command of a table created with serial, you will see it not described/dumped as `serial`.

One thing that using `serial` does it mark the sequence as being owned by the column, so that it will get dropped if the column gets dropped.  You can accomplish this after-the-fact by running something like this:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE public.x_x_seq OWNED BY public.x.x;
```

For new work happening in v13 (or back to v10) you might consider using `generated always as identity` instead.